# Why parentheses returns exit status but not braces

Tags: bash, shell-script

I understand that parentheses cause the commands to be run in a subshell and braces cause the commands to be grouped together but not in a subshell.

When I run this with parentheses:

```
no_func || (
    echo "there is nothing"
    exit 1
)

echo $?
```

This returns the exit status:

```
/Users/myname/bin/ex5: line 34: n_func: command not found
there is nothing
1
```

But when I use braces:

```
no_func || {
    echo "there is nothing"
    exit 1
}

echo $?
```

This doesn't return the exit status.

```
/Users/myname/bin/ex5: line 34: no_func: command not found
there is nothing
```

But why one returns the exit status and another doesn't?

Comment: The former is run in a subshell (= a separate process in bash) and the `exit` will exit just that subshell. The latter is not run in a subshell and the `exit` will terminate your main shell and no `echo $?` will happen. Compare `sh -c '{ exit; }; echo DONE'` vs. `sh -c '(exit); echo DONE'`

Comment: I tested your code by pasting into an interactive Bash. Quite educative, try it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the command execution trace (`set -x`). With braces:

```
+ no_func
./a: line 3: no_func: command not found
+ echo 'there is nothing'
there is nothing
+ exit 1
```

`exit` exits the (sub)shell. Since braces don't create a subshell, `exit` exits the main shell process, so it never reaches the point where it would run `echo $?`.

Answer (score 12):

When you use braces, your script exits with status 1 before it reaches `echo $?` in the script.

Variant with subshell:

```
$ ./script1.sh
./script1.sh: line 3: no_func: command not found
there is nothing 
1 # <-- exit status of subshell
$ echo $?
0 # <-- exit status of script
```

Variant with braces:

```
$ ./script2.sh
./script2.sh: line 3: no_func: command not found
there is nothing # <-- the script exits with 1 after this line
$ echo $?
1 # <-- exit status of script
```